# change values in array when doing foreach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, pass-by-reference

example:

```
var arr = ["one","two","three"];

arr.forEach(function(part){
  part = "four";
  return "four";
})

alert(arr);
```

The array is still with it's original values, is there any way to have writing access to array's elements from iterating function ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6081868/632951

Comment: Try map(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): `x=[2,3,4];
x=x.map(n=>n*2);
// [4,6,8]`

Answer (score 725, accepted):

The callback is passed the element, the index, and the array itself.

```
arr.forEach(function(part, index, theArray) {
  theArray[index] = "hello world";
});
```

*edit* — as noted in a comment, the `.forEach()` function can take a second argument, which will be used as the value of `this` in each call to the callback:

```
arr.forEach(function(part, index) {
  this[index] = "hello world";
}, arr); // use arr as this
```

That second example shows `arr` itself being set up as `this` in the callback.One might think that the array involved in the `.forEach()` call might be the *default* value of `this`, but for whatever reason it's not; `this` will be `undefined` if that second argument is not provided.

(Note: the above stuff about `this` does not apply if the callback is a `=>` function, because `this` is never bound to anything when such functions are invoked.)

Also it's important to remember that there is a whole family of similar utilities provided on the Array prototype, and many questions pop up on Stackoverflow about one function or another such that the best solution is to simply pick a different tool. You've got:

- `forEach` for doing a thing with or to every entry in an array;
- `filter` for producing a new array containing only qualifying entries;
- `map` for making a one-to-one new array by transforming an existing array;
- `some` to check whether at least one element in an array fits some description;
- `every` to check whether *all* entries in an array match a description;
- `find` to look for a value in an array

and so on. [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Thanks! ES6: arr.forEach((o, i, a) => a[i] = myNewVal)

Comment: why `part` (or even `o` in es6) is undefined ? how to get iterated value?

Comment: @DaniilMashkin `part` would be `undefined` if an element of the array has been assigned `undefined` explicitly. "Empty" slots of an array (an array entry that has never been assigned any value) are skipped by `.forEach()` and most other array iteration methods.

Comment: For completeness, `.forEach()` also takes a second argument `thisArg`, which you can use as `this` inside the callback. NOTE: this an argument of `.forEach` NOT an argument of the callback.

Comment: To use the `this` passed as second argument to `.forEach()`, you need to pass the callback function using the syntax `function()`, since using ES6's arrow function `() => {}` does not bind context.

Comment: `this[index] = "hello world";` doesn't work. `this` refers to something else.

Comment: Seems like `map` is what one might want often in this situation. `x=[2,3,4]; x=x.map( n=>2*n) // [4, 6, 8]`. Simple.

Comment: What's the point of including a third argument, `theArray`; can't you do this `arr[index] = "hello world";`

Comment: @Dennis yes, **if** the array involved is in a local scope. There may be situations where explicitly passing in the reference is useful. Admittedly, I have only very rarely found the need to do it. Nevertheless, that's how the API works.

Comment: Can I use a fat arrow operator like `arr.forEach((part, index)=> {this[index] ="helloworld";}, arr);`... wait, Diego got the ES6 solution, maybe explaining why mine does not work might lead to JS collapse;)

Answer (score 160):

Let's *try* to keep it simple and discuss how it is actually working. It has to do with variable types and function parameters.

Here is your code we are talking about:

```
var arr = ["one","two","three"];

arr.forEach(function(part) {
  part = "four";
  return "four";
})

alert(arr);
```

First off, here is where you should be reading about Array.prototype.forEach():

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Second, let's talk briefly about value types in JavaScript.

**Primitives** (undefined, null, String, Boolean, Number) store an actual value.

ex: `var x = 5;`

**Reference Types** (custom objects) store the memory location of the object.

ex: `var xObj = { x : 5 };`

And third, how function parameters work.

In functions, parameters are **always** passed by value.

Because `arr` is an array of Strings, it's an array of **primitive** objects, which means they are stored by value.

So for your code above, this means that each time the forEach() iterates, `part` is equal to the same value as `arr[index]`, **but not the same object**.

`part = "four";` will change the `part` variable, but will leave `arr` alone.

The following code will change the values you desire:

```
var arr = ["one","two","three"];

arr.forEach(function(part, index) {
  arr[index] = "four";
});

alert(arr);
```

Now if array `arr` was an array of **reference types**, the following code will work because reference types store a memory location of an object instead of the actual object.

```
var arr = [{ num : "one" }, { num : "two"}, { num : "three"}];

arr.forEach(function(part, index) {
  // part and arr[index] point to the same object
  // so changing the object that part points to changes the object that arr[index] points to

  part.num = "four";
});

alert(arr[0].num);
alert(arr[1].num);
alert(arr[2].num);
```

The following illustrates that you can change `part` to point to a new object while leaving the objects stored in `arr` alone:

```
var arr = [{ num : "one" }, { num : "two"}, { num : "three"}];

arr.forEach(function(part, index) {
  // the following will not change the object that arr[index] points to because part now points at a new object
  part = 5;
});

alert(arr[0].num);
alert(arr[1].num);
alert(arr[2].num);
```

Comment: indeed, great explanation! It would have been even better to extend the explanation at the other iteration methods, for...of, map, ... The new for...of works in a very similar way than forEach for such cases, except that the "index" is missing for altering eventually the original array (like in forEach). Also ES5 map seems similar to forEach, maybe just that the possibility to return values from a map makes things clearer from a syntax perspective than using the index.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you. After all I can't get this statement:
```In functions, parameters are always passed by value.```

What about the second example?

Comment: @7sides, That statement is describing that function parameters will always be passed by value. So for primitives, it will be the value that the primitive points to. For objects, it will be the location that the object is pointing to. [this w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp) has a good explanation. See sections **Arguments are Passed by Value** and **Objects are Passed by Reference**.

Comment: *In functions, parameters are always passed by value.* BAM. thx. +1

Answer (score 159):

Array: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
Result: `["foo1", "foo2", "foo3", "foo4"]`

### [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) Keep original array

```js
const originalArr = ["Iron", "Super", "Ant", "Aqua"];
const modifiedArr = originalArr.map(name => `${name}man`);

console.log( "Original: %s", originalArr );
console.log( "Modified: %s", modifiedArr );
```

### [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) Override original array

```js
let originalArr = ["Iron", "Super", "Ant", "Aqua"];
originalArr = originalArr.map(name => `${name}man`);

console.log( "Original: %s", originalArr );
```

### [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control) Override original array

```js
const originalArr = ["Iron", "Super", "Ant", "Aqua"];
originalArr.forEach((name, index) => originalArr[index] = `${name}man`);

console.log( "Overridden: %s", originalArr );
```

Comment: "Array.prototype.map() Modify original array, achieved by reassigning arr variable"

.map() never modifies the original array, it creates a new one. Reassignment of the variable does not change the original object.

Comment: `let arr1 = ["1", 2, 3, 4];

arr1.map(function(v) {
  return "foo"+ v;
});

console.log( arr );`

Array.prototype.map() Never Modify original array, forEach mutate.

Comment: @AnupamMaurya That’s not true at all. `map` can definitely mutate its array and `forEach`, in general, doesn’t.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, thanks for the reply. All I want to add, forEach overrides the data, but a map, can not, it creates a new copy.

Comment: Clear than others

Answer (score 18):

Javascript is pass by value, and which essentially means `part` is a *copy* of the value in the array.

To change the value, access the array itself in your loop.

`arr[index] = 'new value';`

Comment: It depends on the type of `part` whether it is copied - although you are right that the variable is not a pointer, but a value

Comment: Saying "JavaScript is pass by value" is a gross generalization. There are reference types in JavaScript. Value types are passed by value.

Comment: Not a gross generalization.  A completely correct and absolute statement.  Javascript passes references by value.  Javascript is pass by value, always.

Comment: @hvgotcodes I was not aware of that. Would you have any links that explained it please?

Comment: @Bergi: No, it does not matter the type. All values are copied on assignment -- the only values in JavaScript are primitives and references. Both primitives and references are copied on assignment.

Comment: @newacct: OK, but I guess not everyone would consider references to be values :-)

Comment: @Bergi just because a language has a thing called a reference, doesn't mean it uses pass by reference.  References can be (and are) passed by value, i.e. the value of the reference is copied and that copy is used as the argument.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a similar answer using using a `=>` style function:

```
var data = [1,2,3,4];
data.forEach( (item, i, self) => self[i] = item + 10 );
```

gives the result:

```
[11,12,13,14]
```

The `self` parameter isn't strictly necessary with the arrow style function, so

```
data.forEach( (item,i) => data[i] = item + 10);
```

also works.

Answer (score 5):

The .forEach function can have a callback function(eachelement, elementIndex)
So basically what you need to do is :

```
arr.forEach(function(element,index){
    arr[index] = "four";   //set the value  
});
console.log(arr); //the array has been overwritten.
```

Or if you want to keep the original array, you can make a copy of it before doing the above process.
To make a copy, you can use:

```
var copy = arr.slice();
```

Comment: If you want to make a copy of the array, use `map()` instead of `forEach()`. `map()` iterates over the source array and returns a new array containing the [modified] copy of the original: the source array is left unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

To add or delete elements entirely which would alter the index, by way of extension of zhujy_8833 suggestion of slice() to iterate over a copy, simply count the number of elements you have already deleted or added and alter the index accordingly. For example, to delete elements:

```
let values = ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8"];
let count = 0;
values.slice().forEach((value, index) => {
    if (value === "A2" || value === "A5") {
        values.splice(index - count++, 1);
    };
});
console.log(values);

// Expected: [ 'A0', 'A1', 'A3', 'A4', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8' ]
```

To insert elements before:

```
if (value === "A0" || value === "A6" || value === "A8") {
    values.splice(index - count--, 0, 'newVal');
};

// Expected: ['newVal', A0, 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'newVal', 'A6', 'A7', 'newVal', 'A8' ]
```

To insert elements after:

```
if (value === "A0" || value === "A6" || value === "A8") {
    values.splice(index - --count, 0, 'newVal');
};

// Expected: ['A0', 'newVal', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'newVal', 'A7', 'A8', 'newVal']
```

To replace an element:

```
if (value === "A3" || value === "A4" || value === "A7") {
    values.splice(index, 1, 'newVal');
};

// Expected: [ 'A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'newVal', 'newVal', 'A5', 'A6', 'newVal', 'A8' ]
```

Note: if implementing both 'before' and 'after' inserts, code should handle 'before' inserts first, other way around would not be as expected

Answer (score 2):

replace it with index of the array.

```
array[index] = new_value;
```

Answer (score 2):

With the Array object methods you can modify the Array content yet compared to the basic for loops, these methods lack one important functionality. You can not modify the index on the run.

For example if you will remove the current element and place it to another index position within the same array you can easily do this. If you move the current element to a previous position there is no problem in the next iteration you will get the same next item as if you hadn't done anything.

Consider this code where we move the item at index position 5 to index position 2 once the index counts up to 5.

```
var ar = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
ar.forEach((e,i,a) => {
i == 5 && a.splice(2,0,a.splice(i,1)[0])
console.log(i,e);
}); // 0 0 - 1 1 - 2 2 - 3 3 - 4 4 - 5 5 - 6 6 - 7 7 - 8 8 - 9 9
```

However if we move the current element to somewhere beyond the current index position things get a little messy. Then the very next item will shift into the moved items position and in the next iteration we will not be able to see or evaluate it.

Consider this code where we move the item at index position 5 to index position 7 once the index counts up to 5.

```
var a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
a.forEach((e,i,a) => {
i == 5 && a.splice(7,0,a.splice(i,1)[0])
console.log(i,e);
}); // 0 0 - 1 1 - 2 2 - 3 3 - 4 4 - 5 5 - 6 7 - 7 5 - 8 8 - 9 9
```

So we have never met 6 in the loop. Normally in a for loop you are expected decrement the index value when you move the array item forward so that your index stays at the same position in the next run and you can still evaluate the item shifted into the removed item's place. This is not possible with array methods. You can not alter the index. Check the following code

```
var a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
a.forEach((e,i,a) => {
i == 5 && (a.splice(7,0,a.splice(i,1)[0]), i--);
console.log(i,e);
}); // 0 0 - 1 1 - 2 2 - 3 3 - 4 4 - 4 5 - 6 7 - 7 5 - 8 8 - 9 9
```

As you see when we decrement `i` it will not continue from 5 but 6, from where it was left.

So keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

##### If you want to remove items

If the change you need to make is to completely remove one or more items from the list you're safer using a `for` loop and going **backwards** through the loop.

```
    for (let i = myArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        const item = myArray[i];

        if (...) 
        {
           // remove item
           // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array?rq=1
        }
    };
```

Going backwards means that the array of each item never changes. If you are going forwards through a loop and delete `item[3]` then `item[4]` is now the new `item[3]`, which doesn't make anything easier. You won't have that issue going backwards.

This is of course a solution not using foreach, but it's important to remember that 'old school' ways can often be best. And if for whatever reason you need to `break;` from the loop (and there are more than a handful of items) a for loop is more efficient since you can't break out of a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this if you want to override

```
var newArray= [444,555,666];
var oldArray =[11,22,33];
oldArray.forEach((name, index) => oldArray [index] = newArray[index]);
console.log(newArray);
```