# Replacing objects inside Angular's forEach()

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array of objects and an `forEach()`, like this one:

```
$scope.things = [
    {x: 2},
    {x: 4},
    {x: 5}
];

angular.forEach($scope.things, function(thing) {

    //Pick one of the lines at a time

    //thing.x += 10;         // <--- works
    //thing.k = thing.x + 1; // <--- works
    //thing = {k: thing.x + 10, o: thing.x - 1};  // <--- doesn't work

    //
});

console.log($scope.things);
```

And by `"works", "works" and "doesn't work"` I mean:

- `x` is added 10, and final array looks as `{x: 12}, {x: 14}, {x: 15}`
- `k` is created, and final array looks as `{x: 2, k: 3}, {x: 4, k: 5}, {x: 5, k: 6}`
- `thing` itself isn't replaced, and the array of `things` looks exactly like at the beginning.

My questions are:

- Why is this happening?
- Is that the expected behavior?
- How can I completely replace each `thing`?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482961/is-it-possible-to-change-values-of-the-array-when-doing-foreach-in-javascript ... It has all the answers you are looking for.

Comment: @Mindastic - Yep.  Even as I wrote my answer below, I thought to myself, "Surely this is a duplicate. There must be an answer here somewhere already."  Thanks for finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

Because `thing` is just a variable.  You can reassign the value of a variable (even a parameter variable) to whatever you want without affecting the values of an object.

> Is that the expected behavior?

Yes

> How can I completely replace each `thing`?

If you want to change the value of an object's property, you need to do just that.  Reference the object and it's property name when you make the assignment.  [The `forEach` iterator function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) is passed `value`, `key`, and `obj`.  So, you can say `obj[key] = { whatever: "you want" }` to change the property value.

```
angular.forEach($scope.things, function(thing, key, things) {

    //Pick one of the lines at a time

    //thing.x += 10;         // <--- works
    //thing.k = thing.x + 1; // <--- works
    //thing = {k: thing.x + 10, o: thing.x - 1};  // <--- doesn't work

    //things[key] = {k: thing.x + 10, o: thing.x - 1}; // <--- works!
});
```