# How do you use the forEach method in Javascript to increment each value in the array by 5?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

How do you use the `forEach` method in Javascript to increment each value in the array by 5? Can someone please give me an example, I'm confused on how to use the syntax for `forEach` in this situation.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post an example of what you've tried.

Comment: `forEach` is not _a syntax_, it is a `method` of `Array`.

Comment: refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12482991/1531476

Comment: "How do you use  forEach to increment each value..." - you don't. You're looking for `.map`.

Answer (score 9):

You should use the [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function instead of `forEach` to increment all the values of your array by 5:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const result = array.map(a => a + 5);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What does **a => a** do? I've seen the arrow function before, but what do the a's represent?

Comment: a => a + 5 is the ES6 syntax for function (a) { return a + 5; }

Answer (score 1):

`map()` is a better option in this case . see the below sample and fiddle

```
var numbers = [1, 5, 10, 15];
var newnum = numbers.map(function(x) {
   return x + 5;
});
console.log(newnum);
```

or you can also use arrow function syntax for ES2015

```
var numbers = [1, 5, 10, 15];
 var newnum = numbers.map(x => x + 5);
console.log(newnum);
```

link to fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/vjzbo9ep/1/

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to apply `Array.forEach` function *to increment each value in the array by 5* while modifying the initial array in-place, use the following:

```js
var arr = [2, 3, 4];
arr.forEach(function(v, i, a){ a[i] += 5; });

console.log(arr);
```