# Array.Map() is changing state without using return value

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit, immer.js, createentityadapter

I am coding along with the Redux Essentials tutorial.

When I run notificationArray.map without using the return value, my state is updated per the map functions callbacks.

I.e. in `allNotifiicationsRead`, each notifications's `read` property is set to `true` in the app state. And in `fetchNotifications`, all each notification's `isNew` property is set to `!read`.

I would expect this `notificationArray.map(...)` call to not have any effect since, I am not using the return value, let alone editing the state with it such as something like `notificationsAdapter.setMany(notificationArray)`.

Any clarification on how this is working would be appreciated.

Please let me know if I didn't include any relevant details about this app.

```
const notificationsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'notifications',
    initialState: notificationsAdapter.getInitialState(),
    reducers: {
        allNotificationsRead(state, action) {
            const notificationArray = Object.values(state.entities)
            notificationArray.map(notification => (
                notification.read = true
            ))
        }
    },
    extraReducers(builder){
        builder.addCase(fetchNotifications.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            notificationsAdapter.upsertMany(state, action.payload)
            const notificationArray = Object.values(state.entities)
            notificationArray.map(notification => (
                notification.isNew = !notification.read
            ))
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: You did not assign the `Array#map` product to anything.

Comment: First of all you shouldn't be using `map()` without a return as that is simply a `forEach()` with additional overhead, but the reason it's mutating your state is that you are directly changing a nested object's properties. `map` doesn't clone the contents of the array it's called on in any way. To avoid the mutation you **should** be using the returned array from the `map()` and you should be cloning each object in the callback `const notificationArray = Object.values(state.entities).map(notification => ({...notification, isNew: !notification.read}));`

Comment: If you don't want to *mutate* the array, you shouldn't have statements that mutate (like `notification.read = true`). The alternative is to copy, but then where do you want to store it -- since you made `notificationArray` a `const`?

Comment: see: [JavaScript: Difference between .forEach() and .map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/javascript-difference-between-foreach-and-map) and [How to mutate original array in Javascript .map() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520833/how-to-mutate-original-array-in-javascript-map-function#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20mutate,can%20use%20Array%23forEach%20function.&text=Array%23map%20creates%20a%20new,to%20assign%20the%20returned%20result.)

Comment: @pilchard Thank you, you explained this behavior perfectly. I didn't recognize here that I was simply modifying the array by writing `.map(notification => (...))` instead of cloning each object with `.map(notification => ({...}))`. It seems like the former will always lead to modifying the original array (as well as not returning a modified array) and therefore an antipattern. Can you point me to a resource that explains exactly what the syntax being used in each is? I.e. `.map(notification => (...))` modifies the array whereas `.map(notification => ({...}))` clones each item.

Comment: It's simply [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) in an object literal which creates a shallow clone of the object which is spread while allowing for properties to be added, or updated using standard object literal syntax.

Comment: The part I was missing was the [syntax of parentheses when returning in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824558/why-use-parentheses-when-returning-in-javascript). As well as the fact that my return value comes from a reassignment, which returns the value of the variable after reassignment. And as you pointed out, the Map callback mutates the array as a side effect (which I know is an antipattern). Everything is crystal clear now. Thanks again!