# Capitalise names - Mutate original array

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

```
const people = [
    "JoHn", "ChrISTiana", "anThoNY", "MARia", "jaMeS", "MIChaEl", "jeNNIFeR"
];
```

I want to capitalise the first letter of each word and lowercase the rest.

I have used the following function to generate a new array:

```
let capitaliseNames = (arr) => {
  return arr.map((item) => item[0].toUpperCase() + item.slice(1).toLowerCase());
};
```

But how do I mutate the original array? I have tried the same approach but using forEach and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Maybe because your `people` is `const`?

Comment: Declare `people` with `let`, then just assign the return value of `capitaliseNames`: `let people = [......];  people = capitaliseNames(people);`.

Comment: @holydragon I think you misunderstand the meaning of `const`.

Comment: You can set the value for each index using `forEach`, e.g. `people.forEach((person, i) => { people[i] = person[0].toUpperCase() + person.slice(1).toLowerCase() });`

Comment: You shouldn't be mutating the array you're iterating over in a `forEach`, @bryce.

Comment: Why is that @Cerbrus?

Comment: @Cerbrus I'd also be interested in the rationale for that statement. We're not talking about inserting/removing elements here.

Comment: @Cerbrus `Arrays are Not Constants`.  It defines a constant reference to an array. So he can

Comment: @angel.bonev: Not sure why you tagged me. I'm not claiming the array is immutable.

Comment: @bryce As MDN puts it: _"Warning: Concurrent modification of the kind described in the previous paragraph frequently leads to hard-to-understand code and is generally to be avoided (except in special cases)."_ (red block in the [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#description)) It's not a hard rule, more of a convention I always followed. Imo, it does keep code easier to maintain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mutate original array in Javascript .map() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520833/how-to-mutate-original-array-in-javascript-map-function)

Comment: @Cerbrus , sorry my bad. I've misunderstood you. Thanks for the clarification. It's a good convention

Comment: @Cerbrus *"Concurrent modification of the kind described in the previous paragraph [...]"*. Yet, what we're doing in this case is decidedly not covered in that previous paragraph...

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen no? _"If existing elements of the array are **changed** or deleted <...>"_

Comment: @Cerbrus, yes, continue reading. The paragraph addresses cases where you modify elements before or after the current index. None of which is being done in this case. There are plenty of cases where an array needs to be modified in place, so your stance is that we have to use a `for` loop for that? Agree to disagree.

Comment: There's nothing to "continue reading" about. That red block talks about _"concurrent modification"_, and _changing_ array entry values is certainly part of that.

Comment: @Cerbrus There is **NO** concurrent modification in this case.

Comment: Hou’re modifying the array you’re ierating over so…

Comment: if you only need it for display in the web interface, look towards the css property text-transform: capitalize;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform

Comment: @Cerbrus I understand that a discussion can be had in favor of immutable state for a number of use cases. However, there are plenty of scenarios where arrays need to be iterated over and modified in-place, and whether you do that with a `for` loop or a `forEach()` loop makes no material difference.

Comment: @loadLT why do you need to mutate a constant array ? What's the problem with that array not to be constant ?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I said it’s just a standard I follow, didn’t I?

Comment: @angel.bonev This was just my curiosity. I know it's not best practice to mutate the original array, but just wanted to know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the work

```
let capitaliseNames = (arr) => { arr.forEach((elem, i) => { arr[i] = elem[0].toUpperCase() + elem.slice(1).toLowerCase() }); };
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution works and is easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

First: `toLowerCase()` then you can use a custom function for the mutation the first letter.

**UPDATE** Use a loop where you can manipulate the original array. For example a for loop.

```js
const people = ["JoHn", "ChrISTiana", "anThoNY", "MARia", "jaMeS", "MIChaEl", "jeNNIFeR"];

for(let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {  
   people[i] = capitalizeFirstLetter( people[i].toLowerCase() ) ;
}

function capitalizeFirstLetter(str) {
  return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}

console.log(people)
```

Comment: The `toLowerCase` was already part of the original `capitaliseNames` function. Why would you move that out of it?

Comment: @Cerbrus I dont recognise that the question owner added the codesnipped.

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach()` instead of `map()` and reassign the mutated value back to the original array:

```js
const people = ["JoHn", "ChrISTiana", "anThoNY", "MARia",
                "jaMeS", "MIChaEl", "jeNNIFeR"];

const capitaliseNames = (arr) => arr.forEach(
  (v, i, a) => a[i] = v[0].toUpperCase() + v.slice(1).toLowerCase()
);

capitaliseNames(people);

console.log(people);
```

Comment: You have my upvode, but personaly I don't think mutating constant arrays is a good practice

Comment: @angel.bonev There are plenty of use cases where that is required. Keep in mind that `map()`-ing that array with the same logic requires twice as much memory. Another example is that sometimes change detection strategies in front-end libraries require the array to be mutated in place instead of copied and reassigned. What's more: there are plenty of built-in functions that will mutate arrays in place, `sort()` probably being the most well-known example.

Comment: just for curiosity why using `a[i] =` and not  `arr[i] =`

Comment: @angel.bonev It keeps the callback self-contained. No external variables are referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Had a go using the for loop and this works:

```
let capitaliseNames = (arr) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i][0].toUpperCase() + arr[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
    }
}
```