# How do you use JavaScript's forEach to modify the contents of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given a JavaScript array, how can you modify the items in an array with the `forEach` operator?

Comment: See [is it possible to change values of the array when doing foreach in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482961/is-it-possible-to-change-values-of-the-array-when-doing-foreach-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple question, but I'm posting the answer so I don't have to figure it out from scratch again. The function called by `forEach` takes three parameters, the current item, the index of that item, and the array object. So, using a `=>` style function, the solution is:

```
var data = [1,2,3,4];
data.forEach( (item, i, self) => self[i] = item + 10 );
```

gives the result:

```
[11,12,13,14]
```

The `self` parameter isn't strictly necessary with the arrow style function, so

```
data.forEach( (item,i) => data[i] = item + 10);
```

also works. You also get the same result using a regular function, e.g.:

```
data.forEach( function(item, i, self) { self[i] = item + 10; } );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're replacing array items, a better way to do this is to use `map` instead:

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
data = data.map(item => item + 10);
```

Comment: I think this would be the better approach in most scenarios, but the question seems to be about modifying the array in place (I didn't downvote though).

Comment: I agree that map would be better, but you should provide an example. Your answer as it stands is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: That is true, I'll update it to add an example. It is true that there are rare cases where you might want to modify an array in place, but I would say that generally using a map is preferred because it's easier to read.