# Is there a way to push a string onto the end of each element in the array(I have to use the while loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

Create a function johnLennonFacts.

This function will accept one argument, an array of facts about John Lennon (note that it might not be exactly the following facts):

```
const facts = [
  "He was the last Beatle to learn to drive",
  "He was never a vegetarian",
  "He was a choir boy and boy scout",
  "He hated the sound of his own voice"
];
```

Use a while loop to loop over the facts array and add "!!!" to the end of every fact.
Return an array of strings with exclamation points.

```
function johnLennonFacts(array) {

    let i = 0;
    while (i < (0, array.length, i++)) {
        array.push('!!!');
    }
    return array;
}
```

I keep returning the original array but I need to add the explanation points to them through the while loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is it possible to change values of the array when doing foreach in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482961/is-it-possible-to-change-values-of-the-array-when-doing-foreach-in-javascript)

Comment: Your code is not appending to the end of each string, you are endlessing appending to the array

Comment: The course is asking me to specifically use certain methods so will not be able to use foreach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `concatenation` not `push`, i.e `push` adds a new element to array whereas your desired output needs to add ( concatenate ) `!!!` at the end of element so use `string concatenation`

```js
const facts = [
  "He was the last Beatle to learn to drive",
  "He was never a vegetarian",
  "He was a choir boy and boy scout",
  "He hated the sound of his own voice"
];

const final = facts.map(e=> e + '!!!')

console.log(final)
```

Your original code can be changed to

```js
function johnLennonFacts(array) {
  let i = 0;
  let newArray = []
  while (i < array.length) {
    newArray.push(array[i] + ' !!!')
    i++
  }
  return newArray;
}

const facts = [
  "He was the last Beatle to learn to drive",
  "He was never a vegetarian",
  "He was a choir boy and boy scout",
  "He hated the sound of his own voice"
];

console.log(johnLennonFacts(facts))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to add new elements to the array when you use `push()`. You need to modify the existing elements' *string values*.

```js
const facts = [
  "He was the last Beatle to learn to drive",
  "He was never a vegetarian",
  "He was a choir boy and boy scout",
  "He hated the sound of his own voice"
];

function makeFactsExciting(array) {
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i] + '!!!';
  }

  return array;
}

console.log( makeFactsExciting(facts) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control)** to modify the original array if you do not want to create a new array i.e. what happens when you use `map()`:

```js
const facts = [
  "He was the last Beatle to learn to drive",
  "He was never a vegetarian",
  "He was a choir boy and boy scout",
  "He hated the sound of his own voice"
];

facts.forEach((v, i) => facts[i] = `${v}!!!`);

console.log(facts);
```