# How to modify values inside the original array in a recursive?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to modify the values in depth in array in nested array and objects
but it seems it's making clone of array 
I tried to do it recursively.

I'm trying to edit each Boolean values to false :

```
 let data = [{ arr: [true, true, false, false], one: { first: [false, true, true, [true, true, false, false, { arr: [true, { tree: { data: { data: { dd: [true, true, false, false, true] } } } }] }]] } }]


  // change all Boolean values to false in example

  actionOnArray(array) {
    array = array.map((ele) => {
      typeof ele === "boolean" && (ele = false)
      return ele
    })
  }


  findArrayInDepth(array, action) {
    if (Array.isArray(array)) {
      actionOnArray(array)
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(array[i]) || (typeof array === "object" && array !== null)) {
          findArrayInDepth(array[i], action)
        }
      }
    } else if (typeof array === "object" && array !== null) {
      for (let key in array) {
        if (Array.isArray(array) || (typeof array === "object" && array !== null)) {
          findArrayInDepth(array[key], action)
        }
      }
    }
  }


findArrayInDepth(data)

console.log(data) // will output the same original array
```

Comment: It was `forEach()` but I just think it maybe could modify whole array with new array modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
actionOnArray(array) {
  array = array.map((ele) => {
    typeof ele === "boolean" && (ele = false)
    return ele
  })
}
```

`array.map` returns a new array, but when you do `array = array.map...` you are not changing the initial array, you are only reassigning your `array` local variable, so it now references the new array. When you call `actionOnArray(array)` you only pass the reference to your array, so when this reference is reassigned it doesn't affect the array contents.

What you need to do is to iterate over the array using a `for` loop and reassign each of its items:

```
function actionOnArray(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
    typeof array[i] === "boolean" && (array[i] = false);
  }
}
```

```js
let data = [{ arr: [true, true, false, false], one: { first: [false, true, true, [true, true, false, false, { arr: [true, { tree: { data: { data: { dd: [true, true, false, false, true] } } } }] }]] } }];


// change all Boolean values to false in example

function actionOnArray(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
    typeof array[i] === "boolean" && (array[i] = false);
  }
}


function findArrayInDepth(array, action) {
  if (Array.isArray(array)) {
    actionOnArray(array)
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (Array.isArray(array[i]) || (typeof array === "object" && array !== null)) {
        findArrayInDepth(array[i], action);
      }
    }
  } else if (typeof array === "object" && array !== null) {
    for (let key in array) {
      if (Array.isArray(array) || (typeof array === "object" && array !== null)) {
        findArrayInDepth(array[key], action);
      }
    }
  }
}


findArrayInDepth(data);

console.log(data);
```

**Note:** if you use

```
array.forEach((ele) => {
  typeof ele === "boolean" && (ele = false)
})
```

it won't change the contents either, because `(ele) => {...}` is a function and hence `ele` is a local variable. This means that if `ele` is a primitive, it will be just a copy of the actual array item.

Take a look at this answer for the detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31298343/8629960

Answer (score 1):

We can write a higher-order mutation function, `mut`, that takes a user-supplied function, `f`, for rewriting values on the input, `x` -

```
const identity = x =>
  x

const mut = (f = identity, x = {}) =>
  Object(x) === x
    ? Object
        .entries(x)
        .reduce
          ( (r, [ k, v ]) => 
              Object.assign(r, { [k]: mut (f, v) })
          , x
          )
    : f (x)
```

Now to solve your problem... For any value, `v`, if it is a Boolean, we will return its inverse, `!v`. Otherwise if `v` is *not* a Boolean, we will return `v` untouched. We encode that as -

```
mut (v => typeof v === 'boolean' ? !v : v, data)
```

Verify it works by running the snippet below -

```js
const mut = (f, x = {}) =>
  Object(x) === x
    ? Object
        .entries(x)
        .reduce
          ( (r, [ k, v ]) => 
              Object.assign(r, { [k]: mut (f, v) })
          , x
          )
    : f (x)


let data =
  [{ arr: [true, true, false, false], one: { first: [false, true, true, [true, true, false, false, { arr: [true, { tree: { data: { data: { dd: [true, true, false, false, true] } } } }] }]] } }]

console.log(JSON.stringify(data))

mut (v => typeof v === 'boolean' ? !v : v, data)

console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```