# Can replace() be used in a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript

Hi so assume I have a `match()` output array where all elements are strings, and i want to replace some of the text inside those strings but using `forEach()` instead of a regular for loop.

lets suppose the output array is

```js
stringsArray = ["<div>some text here</div>","<div>Some other text here</div>"];
```

again the code above is the output of a `match()` of some text. which prints correctly in the console.

```js
let parsedArray = stringsArray.forEach(element => element.replace(/<div>|<\/div>/g,'\n'));
```

for some reason the code above doesn't work, `console.log(parsedArray)` comes back undefined.

should i use a regular for loop instead, if so why?

Comment: `forEach` never returns a value. Are you thinking of `map`?

Comment: oh, i must have them confused sorry

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change values in array when doing foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482961/change-values-in-array-when-doing-foreach)

Answer (score 0):

`forEach()` just iterates through the array. Changes to `element` are only made to that local copy, and are not returned.

Try `map()`, which lets you `return` an altered element:

```
let parsedArray = stringsArray.map(element => { return element.replace(/<div>|<\/div>/g,'\n') });
```